# Python - Acquire value from dictionary depending on location/index in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

From MySQL query I get data which I put into a dictionary "d":

> d = {0: (datetime.timedelta(0,
>   25200),), 1: (datetime.timedelta(0,
>   25500),), 2: (datetime.timedelta(0,
>   25800),), 3: (datetime.timedelta(0,
>   26100),), 4: (datetime.timedelta(0,
>   26400),), 5: (datetime.timedelta(0,
>   26700),)}

I have a list "m" with numbers like:

> m = [3, 4, 1, 4, 7, 4]

I'd like to test "m" and if there is number "4", I'd like to receive another list "h" with hours from "d" where index from list "m" would be corresponding with keys from dictionary "d", so: m[1], m[3], m[5] would get me hours assigned to d[1], d[3], d[5] in list "h":

> h = [7:05:00, 7:15:00, 7:25:00]

I'll appreciate your input for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for, but I'll take a shot:

```
>>> indices = [index for index, i in enumerate(m) if i == 4]
>>> h = [d[i][0] for i in indices]
```

Then you have to process the timedeltas as you want to.

Comment: Thank You for quick and acuarate response!

Answer (score 0):

```
deltas = [str(d[i][0]) for i, j in enumerate(m) if j == 4]
```

produces list of delta representation as strings.

Answer (score 0):

So at each index is an n-tuple of `timedeltas` right? Assuming, from the code, that potentially there could be more than one `timedelta` at each index.
import datetime

```
import datetime

d = {0: (datetime.timedelta(0, 25200),), 1: (datetime.timedelta(0, 25500),), 2: (datetime.timedelta(0, 25800),), 3: (datetime.timedelta(0, 26100),), 4: (datetime.timedelta(0, 26400),), 5: (datetime.timedelta(0, 26700),)}
m = [3, 4, 1, 4, 7, 4]

def something(m, d):
  h = {}
  for index in m:
    if index in d and index not in h:
      for dt in d[index]:
        total = sum([dt.seconds for dt in d[index]])
        hours = total / 3600
        minutes = (total - (3600 * hours)) / 60
        seconds = (total - (3600 * hours) - (60 * minutes))
        h[index] = "%d:%02d:%02d" % (hours, minutes, seconds)
  return h.values()

print something(m, d) # returns exactly what you asked for
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you asking for

```
def hms( td ):
    h = dt.seconds // 3600
    m = dt.seconds%3600 // 60
    s = dt.seconds%60
    return h+td.days*24, m, s


[ hms(d[ m[i] ]) for i in m ]
```

?